# Question about sheaf of regular functions on an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a question on Daniel Perrin's Algebraic geometry, p.42

Now let's see the next image.

[image]

Here, for an affine algebraic set $V$, $D(f) = D_{V}(f) : = V-V(f) = \{ x \in V \ | \  f(x) \neq 0 \} $.

In arguing b), the gluing condition for $\Gamma(D(f), \mathcal{O}_{V}) = \Gamma(V)_{f} \ (f \in \Gamma(V))$, he conclude that for a standard open $D(f)$ and its covering $D(f_{i}) $ we have $V(f) = V(I)$ (where $I$ is the ideal generated by the functions $f_{i}$) and we may assume that there are only a finite number of functions $f_{i}$ (by using that $\Gamma(V)$ is Noetherian).

Then, he let $s_{i}$ be sections of $D(f_{i})$ which can be wrttien as $s_{i} = a_{i}/f_{i}^{n}$.
But now I can't understand this statement (underlined statement of the image). He saids that since there is finite number of $f_{i}$ 's we can use same $n$ for all sections $s_{i}$, But How can we find such nonnegative integer $n$? Using $V(f)=V(I) = V(f_{1}, f_{2}, ... f_{r}) = \cap _{i=1}^{r} V(f_i)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just take $n=\max_i{n_i}$. Write $s_i=a_i/f_i^{n_i}=a_if_i^{n-n_i}/f^n.$

So we can write for all $i$, $s_i=b_i/f_i^n$ for same $n$.

Comment: Wow, Thanks! $a_i$ 's can be varied. :)